# How to reference the first occurence of the class in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors, click

I have an HTML for the FAQ page that looks smth like this:

```html
<dl class="faq_simple ltr">
<dt id="kak-oformit-zakaz-na-sajte" class=""><span class="faq_question_simple_ltr">Toggle 1</span></dt>
<dd class="faq_answer_simple" style="display: none;">
    CONTENT
</dd>
</dl>

<dl class="faq_simple ltr">
    <dt id="kak-vybrat-tovar" class=""><span class="faq_question_simple_ltr">Toggle2</span>
    </dt>
    <dd class="faq_answer_simple" style="display: none;">
    CONTENT 2
    </dd>
</dl>
```

As you can see I have the span class "faq_question_simple_ltr" that I want to show the `<dd class="faq_answer_simple>` on click. In order to do that I have added a JS function:

```
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".faq_question_simple_ltr").click(function(){
                $(".faq_answer_simple").toggle();
                })
        })
    </script>
```

It works but it opens all the "faq_answer_simple" elements on the page, I've tried adding :first-child to the `$(".faq_answer_simple:first-child").toggle();`, but then it stops working completely.

Can you help me, how can I open the first occurence of given class when I click on a give parent class, using js toggle(); function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your actual code you are referring to all the `.faq_answer_simple` elements when you use `$(".faq_answer_simple")` as a selector.

You need to point to the right `.faq_answer_simple` inside the same parent as the clicked element, you can use:

```
$(this).parent().parent().find(".faq_answer_simple").toggle();
```

**Demo:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".faq_question_simple_ltr").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().find(".faq_answer_simple").toggle();
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<dl class="faq_simple ltr">
  <dt id="kak-oformit-zakaz-na-sajte" class=""><span class="faq_question_simple_ltr">Toggle 1</span></dt>
  <dd class="faq_answer_simple" style="display: none;">
    CONTENT
  </dd>
</dl>

<dl class="faq_simple ltr">
  <dt id="kak-vybrat-tovar" class=""><span class="faq_question_simple_ltr">Toggle2</span>
    </dt>
  <dd class="faq_answer_simple" style="display: none;">
    CONTENT 2
  </dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: You are great! Works perfectly. But I don't understand how you reference the first occurence, if you could explain it would be so great. Any way thank you very much.

Comment: @Undry In the click event callback function `$(this)` will refer to the clicked element, so to point to the right element we need to move up to the parent `faq_simple` element so I can find `.faq_answer_simple`. That's why I used `.parent().parent()`.

Comment: Why you need 2 .parent(), with one it's not working :)

Comment: Because the clicked `span` is inside a `dt` which is also inside another `dl`, so we need two `.parent()` call to get to the first common parent with `.faq_answer_simple` which is the `dl` elmeent.

Comment: chŝdk thank you so much, you spend your time to explain things that might be obivous to you, thank you again. You helped so much.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace this line `$(".faq_answer_simple").toggle();` with  `$(this).toggle();`

Comment: No it does not work, as I'm clicking on one element <span> with certain class and want to show another hidden element <dd> with the state of hidded. If I use what you say it hides the element that I click.

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery:

```
$('.faq_answer_simple')[0].toggle()
```

With es6:

```
let firstElem = document.querySelector('.faq_answer_simple')[0];
firstElem.style.display = firstElem.style.display == 'block' ? 'none' : 'block'
```

actually [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53848914/4304864) chŝdk gave is better since it's not hardcoded like this one is. This is just if you always would care just of the first class occurrence.